# pandas - Why can't DataFrame.apply be used to set some columns Categorical

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame, and I'd like to efficiently turn multiple columns into categorical columns. My first thought was to use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` to convert the relevant columns. Using the following example data:

```
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame(dict(name=       ('Earl', 'Eve', 'Alan', 'Randall', 'Danielle'),
                        age=        (    29,    17,     73,        31,         62),
                        gender=     (   'M',   'F',    'M',       'M',        'F'),
                        nationality=(  'US',  'UK',  'CAN',     'CAN',       'US'),
                        height=     ( 182.9, 167.6,  175.3,     170.2,      172.8)),
                   columns=('name', 'age', 'gender', 'nationality', 'height'))
pdf = pdf.set_index('name')
>>> print(pdf)

          age gender nationality  height
name
Earl       29      M          US   182.9
Eve        17      F          UK   167.6
Alan       73      M         CAN   175.3
Randall    31      M         CAN   170.2
Danielle   62      F          US   172.8
```

You can see that the `apply` approach is not working:

```
cat_list = {'gender', 'nationality'}
set_cat_list = lambda x: x.astype('category') if x.name in cat_list else x
dfa = pdf.apply(set_cat_list)

>>> print('Applied to subset: dtype={}'.format(dfa['gender'].dtype))
Applied to subset: dtype=object
```

This does not actually throw an error, it just silently converts the column back from categorical at some point. And to check that it's actually firing correctly, I added a probe:

```
in_cl = lambda x: x.name in cat_list
set_cat_list_alert = lambda x: (set_cat_list(x),
                                sys.stdout.write('{}: {}\n'.format(x.name, in_cl(x))))[0]
dfa = pdf.apply(set_cat_list_alert)
>>> print('Applied to subset: dtype={}'.format(dfa['gender'].dtype))
age: False
age: False
gender: True
nationality: True
height: False
Applied to subset: dtype=object
```

Evidently, everything fires off correctly, so as a test to see if this approach can work at all, I tried just converting *all columns*, and apparently that works just fine:

```
set_cat = lambda x: x.astype('category')
dfb = pdf.apply(set_cat)

>>> print('Applied to whole frame: dtype={}'.format(dfb['gender'].dtype))
Applied to whole frame: dtype=category
```

Finally, I tried just using a `for` loop to duplicate the final result, to make sure that mixed categorical / non-categorical columns can coexist like this:

```
dfc = pdf.copy()
for cat in cat_list:
    dfc[cat] = pdf[cat].astype('category')

>>> print('For loop: dtype={}'.format(dfc['gender'].dtype))
For loop: dtype=category
```

So my question is - why can't `DataFrame.apply()` be used to set some of these columns categorical? What am I missing here?

Comment: what version? your apply code worked for me in `0.16.2`

Comment: Tested with `0.16.2` / Python 3.4.3 and `0.15.2` / Python 2.7.9

Comment: I suspect this is a bug, worth filing an issue on github: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/new.

Comment: @AndyHayden Yeah, good point. I was planning on doing that if it turned out to be a bug not a feature.

Comment: This is fixed in 0.17.0, releasing 1st week of october. you can ``conda install pandas -c pandas`` to get it now if you'd like (the rc1)

Comment: @Jeff Appreciate it. Do you want to convert your comment to an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug, indicated by this issue [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9573), and fixed in the upcoming `0.17.0` release, due first week of october.

you can install the `0.17.0rc1` by:

`conda install pandas -c pandas`